# How to initialize JAX-RS HttpHeaders

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-rs

I have an internal framework with a class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class POSEnterpriseResource extends SynchronousResource {
  ...
  @Inject
  protected HttpHeaders headers;
  ...
}
```

And I need to write unit tests for a class that extends it to use code like

```
String acceptMediaType = headers.getHeaderString("Accept");
String acceptVersion = headers.getHeaderString("Accept-Version");
```

The HttpHeaders type in question is an interface under `javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders` and does not expose any initialization methods, only getters. I do not get to touch the existing code.

How do I mock a headers object like this without setting up a whole ResponseEntity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a mocking library like [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org). Here's how to set up the test

```java
// set up the runner so Mockito handles all the 
// initialization and injections
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Testing {

    // HttpHeaders is mocked and injected into test
    @Mock
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    // HttpHeaders is injected into the resource class field
    @InjectMocks
    private TestResource resource;

    @Test
    public void testHttpHeaders() {
        // control what the mock returns when certain methods are called
        when(headers.getHeaderString("X-Test")).thenReturn("X-Test-Value");
    }
}
```

And below is a complete test to show you the general way to testing using the library. If you've never used the library before, I suggest taking some time to go through the docs. It's pretty easy to learn the basics.

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Testing {

    @Mock
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    @InjectMocks
    private TestResource resource;

    @Test
    public void testHttpHeaders() {
        when(headers.getHeaderString("X-Test")).thenReturn("X-Test-Value");

        String response = resource.get();
        assertThat(response).isEqualTo("X-Test-Value");
    }


    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {

        @Inject
        private HttpHeaders headers;

        @GET
        @Produces("text/plain")
        public String get() {
            return headers.getHeaderString("X-Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using some convoluted legacy code that acts up with Mockito injects but I guess this is the solution under normal circumstances

Comment: Are you already using a runner for your tests? Sometimes using multiple runners can conflict with each other. You don't have to use the runner. You can manually do the injection with [MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html). Also try to use the `@Rule` like at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397937/2587435)

Comment: Unfortunately the class I am testing itself is kind of unusual and I do not think I can really express it well here. I ended up creating the beans manually with a `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`

Comment: Also consider constructor injection as opposed to field injection. It is preferred for this exact case; it is much easier to unit test when using constructor injection. You can mock all the dependencies and just instantiate the class to test, passing in all the mocks. Or even use setter injection. Field injection is the least desirable when it comes to testing.

Comment: **You will have a null value if you are using spring boot 2.4.X**  

As mentioned here: [776616369](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26509#issuecomment-776616369)  

_**The best way to do this is to use a new instance of HttpHeaders**_

Answer (score 1):

Using Mockito, you can mock the behaviour of the getX methods to return stubs exactly as you want. I find Paul's answer complete enough. Also, mockito.mock actually allows you to mock Interfaces.